# If $p(t)'$ and $p(t)''$ are continuously differentiable and converging to zero as $t$ goes to infinity. What can I say of $p(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis

EDIT: I have edited the question with an apparently more relax condition (from uniformly continuous to continuously differentiable derivatives).

I am in the middle of a physics/calculus problem that I do not know how to give a rigorous solution (if it is possible with the following information).

My velocity $\dot p(t)$ is continuously differentiable and converges to zero. My acceleration $\ddot p(t)$ is also continuously differentiable and converges to zero. In fact, all the $n$ derivatives are continuously differentiable and converge to zero.

Then, can I say that $p(t)$ will converge to a finite point?

Comment: When you say the derivative converges to 0, you mean at $+\infty$?

Comment: yes, as $t$ goes to infinity

Comment: Ok, in that case there are counterexamples as already said in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $p(t)= \ln t$. Then $p(t) \to \infty$, but $p^{(k)}(t) \to 0$ for all $k \ge 1$.

Comment: thanks a lot for the counter example